# SharpDx from Nuget

Tags: sharpdx

I'm trying to get the SharpDx DLLs from Nuget instead of accessing the DLLs directly, and it is a nightmare for me - I've spent several hours on this task already.

If I do this:

1. Create a clean project
2. Use "Managde Nuget packages for
   soultion" to install all the SharpDx files, in the same order as in which they appear

Then a lot of things is missing in the SharpDx.D3DCompiler namespace, for example there is no "Module" class.

I have tried to install the compiler (although it already appears under References) manually:

```
PM> Install-Package SharpDX.D3DCompiler
Attempting to resolve dependency 'SharpDX (≥ 2.6.2)'.
Installing 'SharpDX.D3DCompiler 2.6.2'.
Successfully installed 'SharpDX.D3DCompiler 2.6.2'.
Adding 'SharpDX.D3DCompiler 2.6.2' to factor10.VisionQuest.
Successfully added 'SharpDX.D3DCompiler 2.6.2' to factor10.VisionQuest.
Installing [SharpDX.D3DCompiler] to project [C:\proj\VisionQuest\src\SharpDx\factor10.VisionQuest\factor10.VisionQuest\factor10.VisionQuest.csproj]
Exception calling "SetMetadataValue" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file "C:\proj\VisionQuest\src\SharpDx\factor10.VisionQuest\packages\SharpDX.Toolkit.2.6.2\build\SharpDX.Toolkit.targets"."
At C:\proj\VisionQuest\src\SharpDx\factor10.VisionQuest\packages\SharpDX.D3DCompiler.2.6.2\tools\Install.ps1:33 char:1
+ $sharpdx_reference.SetMetadataValue("HintPath", '$(SharpDXPackageBinDir)\{0}.dll ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

But as you can see, I get an error then which I don't understand, and I'm not sure if it is relevant.

Please help!

Comment: which version of nuget is used?

Comment: Version 2.7.40911.287

Comment: It is almost one year old, they did lots of bugfixes, try to upgrade to latest 2.8.x

Comment: Thanks, I have upgraded. After fiddling with my exisiting projects, it actually feels much more stable, but notably, things are still missing from the SharpDx.D3DCompiler namespace while all assemblies seems to be in place!?

Comment: On which type of project do you try to install this? Did you have a close look at https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/wiki/Installation ? (actually, the wiki is missing the d3dcompiler part :D )